# Set Css Class to Dynamic Rows in ASP.Net GridView Control with TextBoxes

Tags: asp.net, css, gridview, textbox

I used this example about [Adding Dynamic Rows in ASP.Net GridView Control with TextBoxes](http://archive.aspsnippets.com/post/2009/06/10/Adding-Dynamic-Rows-in-ASPNet-GridView-Control-with-TextBoxes.aspx) in my .net application. now i need to add `css` style to `TextBoxes` in this GridView. I have added `CssClass="txtbox"` to text boxes in my aspx page. but style is not applied.

How can i do this?

Comment: no problems with css class.

Comment: provide your aspx page html and css class